# Pass form variables from load <div> into the same <div> via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass the variables from the form which was loaded from jquery clicked. Into the same div. I tried test it but none of them works. Here's my script :

**Javascript**

```
//login
function login(){
    $('#prop_form').load('inc/prop_form_login.php');
    $('.axn_btn').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('click', '#submit', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var jsURL = $(this).serialize()+"&lang=$_GET[lang]";
       submit(jsURL);
    });
});

function submit(jsURL){
    $.ajax({
        url:'login_chk.php',
            type :'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $('#prop_form').html(data);
            }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="prop_form">
<div class="axn_btn">
<a onClick="login()">login</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**login_chk.php**

```
<?
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($_POST[data]);exit();//for testing purpose
.
.
.
?>
```

I expect the login form data to display in the `#prop_form`. But the page refresh with return data from `login_chk.php`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but in the success function, instead of `$('#prop_form').html(data);`, maybe what you're after is `$('#prop_form').load('inc/prop_form_login.php');` or `$('#prop_form').html(jsURL)`.  If it's the second of these, you will need ot make `jsURL` a global variable.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you tell us what this should actually do we can help. It almost looks like you are attempting to login a user, if so, this can be done much more simply

Comment: The `prop_form_login.php` is well loaded after the the login button clicked.  But when I click submit in the form. It cannot display the form variables in the `#prop_form` but it open the `login_chk.php` instead.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, I want the form variables from `prop_login_form.php` (which is simple form) to display in `#prop_form` without refresh.

Comment: @Wilf you do serialize and pass it to the function `submit` but than you don't do anything with `jsURL`.You need to send it as `data` to `login_chk.php` to get it back inside your `success` function as variable `data`

Comment: @HakanKose, Would be appreciate if you can explain your paragraph with code.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do with your code. I'm trying to get at **why** you are doing this. I can't see why you'd need to send data to a php page that sends that same data right back to the ajax callback which simply puts that same data right back where it got it from. Surely you are trying to accomplish something and, whatever that is, there will be a simpler way than this if you explain what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the script is working now. Thank you very much for @khairul.ikhwan and @Hakan Kose. You guys are great!

Here is the script:

```
//login 
function login(){ 
    $('#prop_form').load('inc/prop_form_login.php', function(){
        $("#login_form").on('click', '#submit', function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var jsURL = $('form').serialize()+"&lang=<?=$_GET[lang]?>"; 
            submit(jsURL); 
        });
    }); 
    $('.axn_btn').hide(); 
} 

function submit(jsURL){
    $.ajax({
        url:'login_chk.php',
            type :'POST',
            data: {data: jsURL},
            success: function(data){
                $('#prop_form').html(data);
            }
    });
}
```

I can't accept both of your codes in the same post. But please know that you guys are part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT
This must do the job;

```
function login(){
    $('#prop_form').load('inc/prop_form_login.php');
    $('.axn_btn').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('click', '#submit', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var getLang = <?php echo "'" . $_GET['lang'] . "'"?>;
       var jsURL = $(this).serialize()+"&lang=" + getLang;
       submit(jsURL);
    });
});
function submit(jsURL){
    $.ajax({
        url:'login_chk.php',
            type :'POST',
            data: {data: jsURL},
            success: function(data){
                $('#prop_form').html(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Than for example in your `login_chk.php`

```
<?php 
    // This echo will be showed in you success function as data
    echo $_POST["data"];
?>
```

Comment: You allready passing that in `var jsURL = $(this).serialize()+"&lang=$_GET[lang]";` Whatever you var jsURL is that will be passed to you `login_chk.php`

Comment: Yeah, I already passed it but it's not go with the form. When I test `print_r($_POST)`. The var `lang` is empty.

Comment: Try `lang: <?php echo $_GET['lang']; ?>`

Comment: Yeah, I tried. This is the text from source code `data:{data: jsURL,lang:en},`. It works but not sent.

Comment: Try like this `var getLang = <?php echo $_GET['lang']; ?>;` than `lang: getLang`

Comment: Seems like the form information was not sent by ajax. I tried `print_r($_POST[data]);` in `login_chk.php`. It shows me this => `Notice: Undefined index: data in /home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/login_chk.php on line 4`

Comment: Please keep in mind that the form is in DOM. I loaded it from `login` link.

Comment: Hakan, thank you for the try. But it still refresh the page. A solution from khairul.ikhwan is not refresh but the data is not sent.

Comment: Yes I see put my submit function into his code and you'll get the data

Answer (score 1):

You load the form on click but you are binding the onclick event to the submit button on document ready. The form is still not loaded yet. Perhaps you can try move belows code to the callback after you load the login form in the function login()

**Edit : use belows code see if it work.**

```
//login 
function login(){ 
    $('#prop_form').load('inc/prop_form_login.php', function(){
        $("form").on('click', '#submit', function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var jsURL = $(this).serialize()+"&lang=$_GET[lang]"; 
            submit(jsURL); 
        });
    }); 
    $('.axn_btn').hide(); 
} 

function submit(jsURL){ 
    $.ajax({ 
        url:'login_chk.php', 
        type :'POST', 
        success: function(data){ 
            $('#prop_form').html(data); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `move belows code to the callback after you load the login form` ?

Comment: Yeah, the page is not refresh but the data is not pass to `login_chk.php`. It throws me this : `Notice: Undefined index: data in /home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/login_chk.php on line 4`